# Is there a way to set the placeholder color of a UITextField with UIAppearance

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uiappearance

I have found that I can set the placeholder color by changing the `textColor` of a label contained with `UITextField`.

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITextField class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

But this also changes `UITextField` text color. Is there a way to specify them both separately from `UIAppearance`?

I tried to use the the `setValue:forKey:` but then I read that my app can be rejected for using KVC.

Comment: Use the `attributedPlaceholder` property of `UITextField` instead.

Comment: this is wonderful but this must be set on each page correct in a function? i set it in the appDelegate but i am required to give a placeholder string which overrights my placeholders

Comment: Yeah, looking at the way UITextField is built there does not appear to be a way to adjust the placeholder color via an appearance selector, meaning you will have to do it every time. Perhaps an easier alternative in your case is to just subclass UITextfield. Then you can perform your standard customizations by overriding the initializer and other appropriate methods.

Comment: @Snymax you could add a category on `UITextField` to set the `attributedPlaceholder` with a default color - `setDefaultStyledPlaceholder:` for example

Comment: Dima I think your a genius thank you i dont know why i didnt think of that

Answer (score 0):

Building off @Synmax answer, I've put together this category you can use to add a placeholder text color to a UITextField:

```
@interface UITextField (Placeholder)

@property UIColor* placeholderTextColor;

@end

@implementation UITextField (Placeholder)

-(UIColor*)placeholderTextColor {
    return [self.attributedPlaceholder attribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName atIndex:0 effectiveRange:nil];
}

-(void)setPlaceholderTextColor:(UIColor*)placeholderTextColor {
    if(self.attributedPlaceholder) {
        NSMutableAttributedString* as = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedPlaceholder];
        if(placeholderTextColor) {
            [as setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:placeholderTextColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName] range:NSMakeRange(0, self.attributedPlaceholder.length)];
        } else {
            [as removeAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName range:NSMakeRange(0, self.attributedPlaceholder.length)];
        }
        self.attributedPlaceholder = as;
    } else if(self.placeholder) {
        self.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.placeholder attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:placeholderTextColor forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName]];
    }
}

@end
```

You can then set the placeholder text color using appearance like this...

```
[UITextField appearance].placeholderTextColor = UIColor.grayColor;
```